# WebApi Attribute routing not working with [FromUri]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi method as shown below

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("students")]
public string Get([FromUri]Student student)
{
    return "value";
}
```

and my webapiconfig is

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

When i dont use the [Route("..")] attribute then i get the student object populated and it is null if i use [Route("..")].

Can anyone please help how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: What URL are you requesting?

Comment: When i access http://localhost:65190/students => student parameter is null and

Comment: When i access http://localhost:65190/assets?name=test , t hen the student parameter is not null

Comment: Can you please add `Student` definition, it may help to diagnose problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `[Route("students")]` the following URL will match `http://localhost/students?Name=name&Age=12` assuming your `Student` class has `Name` and `Age` properties.

When you don't provide any query parameter it will be null and it's expected behavior.

If you `Student` object is a `struct` it will be required parameter, so you will get exception from WebApi, not null

Comment: Yes. but that is what i am expecting. It works if i use custommodelbinder along with [FromUri] attribute.

Comment: Strange, I have exactly the same code as you have and it works for me without `custommodelbinder` but only with `[FromUri]`

Answer (score 0):

simply, check if its null

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("students")]
public string Get([FromUri] Student student)
{
    if (student == null)
        student = new Student();
    return "value";
}
```